# Orchestrator for complex calculations and rules using .NET

Tags: .net, workflow

I'm developing a system logic for complex calculations (pricing calculations), which evolves multiple variables and multiple formulas, depending on what the user selected. I'm researching a way to build a good architecture for this, mainly an orchestrator class which calls other layers (Database, business logic). The challenge for me is to have a method that is scalable, so I can add rules and maintain the code clean and legible.

One tool I have come across is [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj684582.aspx) (and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx)), but it would be a good way to organize and act as an orchestrator? Any other tools you can recommend?

Comment: I have edited your question a little, but doubt that this question is fit for [softwarerecs.se]. *Either* you ask for a list of products and then this question here needs more requirements (see [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)), *or* you ask at [Programmers.SE] but you make sure it is not a question asking for tool recommendations (which is off-topic there).

Comment: 'Rule engine' is the correct term here.